# Why closure in ajax call has access to the outer scope?

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

I read about JavaScript closures and I thought that I understood it, but apparently I didn't.

The **success** function is called when request is succeeded. This means that when the closure `(function () {
                            return obj;
                        })();` is executed the scope, inside **success** function, is **NOT** `function (evt) {...}` anymore, so how it can still access **obj**?

How the closure work in this example

**EDITED**(there is **var** before **obj**)

```
function (evt) {
           var obj = evt.data.obj,
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: data,
                success: function () {
                    var o = (function () {
                        return obj;
                    })();
                }                    
            });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JS, scope is limited by function.

Everything inside a function to which a variable is scoped can access that variable — including other functions — unless there is another variable of the same name in a narrower scope.

<strike><del>That said, in this example there is no `var` keyword to localise the scope of the `obj` anyway, so it is a global.</del></strike> Removed after edit of question

Comment: sorry for misleading, but there is **var** keyword before **obj** variable

Answer (score 1):

One way to look at it is that closures have access to all scopes above themselves.

Another way would be to say that `obj` actually **is** accessible in scope of function `function(evt)`, which is parent to the scope of `function()`, and therefore, `obj` is also accessible from `function()`.

Either way, this is how JavaScript works: closure has access to everything that is accessible at the closure's point of definition.

Answer (score 1):

A closure has access to **all** higher scopes, not only the "parent scope".

Answer (score 0):

Since an `obj` variable isn't defined in the current scope, JavaScript goes up all the scopes the function has access to until it finds it.

It's like someone looking up a very weird ladder; one which can split to sub-ladders, but when you climb down these sub-ladders, you are still in the bigger ladder.

Answer (score 0):

A closure has by design access to surrounding scope upon creation as it is created within the scope.

Any variables you access in the outer scope is accessed through a reference that will keep the variable alive after the scope within which it was created is destroyed.

That way when the closure executes, the variables it was referencing will still exist and only after the closure is disposed will the variables be released.

Answer (score 0):

Each Function object has an Activation object that represents it's execution context.
Within a group of nested functions, A scope chain is formed starting from the inner most Activation object and ending with the Global object (Global Scope).
So unless there's a name clash between variables ,Each function has access to all of it's parent functions' local variables and parameters in addition to global variables.
[Here](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/)'s a lengthy but very useful explanation.